# Difference between WaitAll and SignalAndWait methods

Tags: c#

I wanted to understand the difference between `WaitAll()` and `SignalAndWait()` methods in C# Threading

Comment: You are speaking about WaitHandle?

Answer (score 0):

`WaitAll()` is for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`s.  It allows the *current thread* to possibly return to the thread pool for higher concurrency, by allowing the operating system to handle IO Completion ports.

`SignalAndWait()` is used for `System.Threading.WaitHandle`s.

[A `WaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Encapsulates operating system–specific objects that wait for exclusive access to shared resources.

So the difference is pretty massive.  They work with different types for completely different reasons.  There is little to no overlap.

Answer (score -2):

**WaitAll**

Waits for all the elements in the specified array to receive a signal.

**SignalAndWait**

Signals that a participant has complete and waits for all other participants to complete